# Laravel and selectize add option

Tags: laravel, selectize.js

I use laravel 5.6 and selectize, everything work great but I won't be able to add option or to set value with jQuery.

Here my code :

```
var select_user, $select_user;
$select_user = $('#select-user').selectize();
select_user = $select_user[0].selectize;
select_user.addOption({id: 10, name: 'name'});
```

And my html :

```
<select id="select-user" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Sélectionnez un utilisateur" required>
    <option value="">Sans</option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I have my users from my bdd but not my added one. No error message too.

Someone can tell me where I'm wrong ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Use different vars in js `var select_user, $user;`

Comment: Nothing change :(

Comment: Note: this does not refresh the options list dropdown (use refreshOptions() for that).